# Magento: neither front-end not admin opening up

Tags: magento

I am using Magento CE v1.7

In both cases, this is what I see:

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

### Error log record number: 376160589307

Answer (score 0):

Go to your root magento installation folder and locate var/report folder  and look for the file with name  376160589307. Please open it to view the exact error.

If you want to display it in browser itself,

Go to your root magento installation folder and locate /errors folder. There you’ll find a

`local.sample.xml or sample.local.xml and rename it to local.xml` in same location